# Positioning a modal, with support to scrollbars, correctly

Tags: css

I need a modal, positioned at the center, with support to dynamic content height and with support to scrollbars in case the content height is greater than the screen.

Here's my attempt:

```css
#outer {
  position: fixed;
  margin: auto;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  max-height: calc(100vh - 80px);
  height: 100%;
}

#inner {
  background-color: #0000FF;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.content-item {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="outer">
      <div id="inner">
        <div class="content-item" style="background-color: red">My Content</div>
        <div class="content-item">My Content</div>
        <div class="content-item">My Content</div>
        <div class="content-item">My Content</div>
        <div class="content-item">My Content</div>
        <div class="content-item">My Content</div>
        <div class="content-item">My Content</div>
        <div class="content-item">My Content</div>
        <div class="content-item">My Content</div>
        <div class="content-item">My Content</div>
        <div class="content-item">My Content</div>
        <div class="content-item">My Content</div>
        <div class="content-item">My Content</div>
        <div class="content-item">My Content</div>
        <div class="content-item">My Content</div>
        <div class="content-item" style="background-color: yellow">My Content</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The problem is... if content is not greater than screen, it will occuppy full height (try leaving only the first and last .content div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution:

```css
#outer {
  position: fixed;
  margin: auto;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  max-height: calc(100% - 80px);
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #0000FF;
  color: #FFF;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.content-item {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">
    <div class="content-item" style="background-color: red">My Content</div>
    <div class="content-item">My Content</div>
    <div class="content-item">My Content</div>
    <div class="content-item">My Content</div>
    <div class="content-item">My Content</div>
    <div class="content-item">My Content</div>
    <div class="content-item">My Content</div>
    <div class="content-item">My Content</div>
    <div class="content-item">My Content</div>
    <div class="content-item">My Content</div>
    <div class="content-item">My Content</div>
    <div class="content-item">My Content</div>
    <div class="content-item">My Content</div>
    <div class="content-item">My Content</div>
    <div class="content-item">My Content</div>
    <div class="content-item" style="background-color: yellow">My Content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).